# Как называется штука, которая изменяет размер?

Tags: c#, winforms

Когда подбираешься к краю окна, как называется стрелка, которая меняет размер?

И самое главное: как её вызвать?

Пытался через

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wparam, int lparam);

SendMessage(Handle, ??, 0, 0);
```

Но ничего не вышло. Я даже не знаю, каким образом такое гуглить.

Comment: Курсор? Двусторонняя стрелка — это просто форма курсора.

Comment: А вызвать её просто: подвести курсор к окну, которое правильно обрабатывает `WM_NCHITTEST`.

Comment: Что значит вызвать ее? Вы хотите изменить тип курсора? Глобально или при наведении на какой-то свой контрол (форму)?

Comment: @АндрейNOP нужно просто на время превратить курсор в стрелочку, что бы можно было менять размер, и в любой части окна.

Comment: Смотрите свойство `Cursor` вашей формы. Но только лишь поменять тип курсора недостаточно для того, чтобы можно было менять размеры.

Comment: Возможно, вам следует посылать сообщение [WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms632622(v=vs.85).aspx), если вы хотите менять размер окна.